# Why do I need a test function to prove a Dirac delta identity?

Tags: intuition, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I'm working on a couple proofs of Dirac delta identities:

$$x \delta '(x)=-\delta (x)$$ and

$$x^{2}\delta''(x)=2\delta(x).$$

I managed to prove them both without using a test function, but everywhere I look says that you need a test function to prove them, but without actually saying why. Can someone provide some intuition for this?

As a side note, I know I can define the delta function as an operator (within an integral), but that doesn't explain why I didn't need to "operate" on a function to prove these identities. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
My proofs (where all integrals are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$):

$\int x\delta'(x)dx\rightarrow$Integrate by parts$\rightarrow=x\delta(x)|^{\infty}_{-\infty}-\int\delta(x)dx=0-1=-1=-\int \delta(x)dx$

$\int x^{2}\delta''(x)dx=x^{2}\delta'(x)|^{\infty}_{-\infty}-2\int x\delta'(x)dx=0-2(x\delta(x)|^{\infty}_{-\infty}-\int \delta(x)dx)=-2(0-1)=2=2\int \delta(x)dx$

Comment: Can you post your proofs as well? It's hard to answer otherwise. But roughly, its analogous to saying : "in order to prove something about a function $f$, you need to work with the value of $f$ on points x, $f(x)$." This is vacuously true, because a function (like a functional) is defined by what it does to points in the domain... but you don't always need to return to working pointwise, if you have other facts at your disposal...

Comment: **$x \delta'(x)$ doesn't mean anything** without a test function it acts on (well $\delta(x)$ too but for $x \delta'(x)$ it is even worse)

Comment: I think you proofs are fine for physicists. BUT your math teacher won't like them.

Answer (score 2):

1. A [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) $u\in {\cal D}^{\prime}$ is by definition a continuous linear functional on the vector space ${\cal D}$ of test functions.
2. Therefore to e.g. prove that a distribution $u=0$ is the zero distribution, one must in principle check that $u[f]=0$ for all test functions $f\in{\cal D}$.
3. OP wants to prove 2 distributional identities. If we (in a slight abuse of notation) denote the identity map $x\mapsto x$ with just $x$, then OP's  distributional identities read
   $$\delta +x \delta^{\prime}~=~0, \qquad x^2 \delta^{\prime\prime}-2\delta ~=~0.\tag{1}$$
4. Let us list a few definitions from distribution theory for clarity. Here $\delta\in {\cal D}^{\prime}$ denotes the [Dirac delta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) 
   $$\delta[f]~:=~f(0), \qquad f~\in~{\cal D}.\tag{2}$$
   Multiplication $gu$ of a distribution $u$ with a smooth function $g$ is defined as
   $$ (gu)[f]~:=~u[g f], \qquad f~\in~{\cal D},\qquad g~\in~C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), \qquad u~\in~{\cal D}^{\prime}. \tag{3} $$
   Also the derivative $u^{\prime}$ is defined as
   $$ u^{\prime}[f]~:=~-u[f^{\prime}], \qquad f~\in~{\cal D}, \qquad u~\in~{\cal D}^{\prime}. \tag{4} $$ 
   (The minus in definition (4) is inspired by the well-known minus from [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).)
5. In the presumably most favorable distributional interpretation of OP's flawed proof (v2) (i.e. using evaluation a la definition (2)-(4), and eliminating the need for actual integrations), he is essentially evaluating the distributional identities (1) for the constant test function $f=1$, which is *not* considered a valid test function. (We typically demand that a test function $f$ has compact support, or alternatively, we use Schwartz test functions. Definition (3) is valid in the former case.)
6. It is not always necessary to spell out the test functions explicitly. E.g. the distributional identities (1) can be seen as derivative consequences 
   $$ 0~=~(x  \delta)^{\prime}~=~\delta +x \delta^{\prime},\tag{5} $$
   $$ 0~=~(x ^2 \delta)^{\prime\prime}-4(x  \delta)^{\prime}  
   ~=~x^2 \delta^{\prime\prime}-2\delta,\tag{6} $$
   of the distribution identities
   $$ x \delta~=~0, \qquad x^2  \delta~=~0 .\tag{7}$$
   We leave it to the reader to prove (7).

Comment: you proof reduces to defining $x \delta'(x)$, and more generally the multiplication of a distribution by a $C^\infty$ function. If $\psi \in C^\infty$ and $T \in D'$ then for any $\varphi \in C^\infty_c$ : $$\langle \psi T,\varphi \rangle =\langle  T,\psi\varphi \rangle $$
(which is well-defined since $\psi\varphi \in C^\infty_c$) also you need to prove that $\varphi \mapsto \psi \varphi$ is a continuous linear mapping of the test function space, so that $\psi T$ is a distribution.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Agree.